# No such property: org for class: org.grails.plugins.log4jxml.Log4jConfigurationInitializer while setup grails 2.0.0

Tags: grails-2.0

While im running 'grails war' im getting the following exception

| Error Error loading plugin manager: Could not create a new instance of class [Log4jXmlGrailsPlugin]! (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --ver
bose to see entire trace.)
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [Log4jXmlGrailsPlugin]!
        at _PluginDependencies_groovy$_run_closure5_closure23.doCall(_PluginDependencies_groovy:178)
        at _PluginDependencies_groovy$_run_closure5_closure23.doCall(_PluginDependencies_groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at _PluginDependencies_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_PluginDependencies_groovy:176)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:60)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
        at _GrailsWar_groovy$_run_closure4.doCall(_GrailsWar_groovy:92)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
        at War$_run_closure1.doCall(War.groovy:38)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: org for class: org.grails.plugins.log4jxml.Log4jConfigurationInitializer
Possible solutions: log
        at org.grails.plugins.log4jxml.Log4jConfigurationInitializer.init(Log4jConfigurationInitializer.groovy:21)
        at org.grails.plugins.log4jxml.Log4jConfigurationInitializer.(Log4jConfigurationInitializer.groovy:12)
        at Log4jXmlGrailsPlugin.(Log4jXmlGrailsPlugin.groovy:16)
        ... 53 more
| Error Error loading plugin manager: Could not create a new instance of class [Log4jXmlGrailsPlugin]!

What is that 'org' property to be in Log4jConfigurationInitializer class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due the fact that you have a log4j-xml plug-in in the project plug-ins.

just remove and it will go away!

Answer (score 0):

log4j-xml plugin is a valid and useful plugin for grails 1.3.x versions. So applications that have a log4j.xml file for logging behavior would find this plugin useful. I do not think that this is the correct solution to the above problem.